# multi threaded FastCGI App

Tags: multithreading, cgi, fastcgi

I want to write a FastCGI app which should handle multiple simultaneous requests using threads. I had a look at the [threaded.c](https://github.com/luislavena/fcgi/blob/master/examples/threaded.c) sample which comes with the SDK:

```
#define THREAD_COUNT 20
static int counts[THREAD_COUNT];

static void *doit(void *a)
{
    int rc, i, thread_id = (int)a;
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    FCGX_Request request;
    char *server_name;

    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);

    for (;;)
    {
        static pthread_mutex_t accept_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
        static pthread_mutex_t counts_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

        /* Some platforms require accept() serialization, some don't.. */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&accept_mutex);
        rc = FCGX_Accept_r(&request);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&accept_mutex);

        if (rc < 0)
            break;

        server_name = FCGX_GetParam("SERVER_NAME", request.envp);

        FCGX_FPrintF(request.out,…
        …     

        FCGX_Finish_r(&request);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    pthread_t id[THREAD_COUNT];

    FCGX_Init();

    for (i = 1; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++)
        pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, doit, (void*)i);

    doit(0);

    return 0;
}
```

In the [FastCGI specification](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node/22#S4) there is an explaination, how the web server will determine how many connections are supported by the FastCGI app:

> The Web server can query specific
>   variables within the application. The
>   server will typically perform a query
>   on application startup in order to to
>   automate certain aspects of system
>   configuration.
>
> …
>
> •  FCGI_MAX_CONNS: The maximum number
>   of concurrent transport connections
>   this application will accept, e.g. "1"
>   or "10".
>
> •  FCGI_MAX_REQS: The maximum number
>   of concurrent requests this
>   application will accept, e.g. "1" or
>   "50".
>
> •  FCGI_MPXS_CONNS: "0" if this
>   application does not multiplex
>   connections (i.e. handle concurrent
>   requests over each connection), "1"
>   otherwise.

But the return values for this query are hard coded into the FastCGI SDK and returns 1 for FCGI_MAX_CONNS and FCGI_MAX_REQS and 0 for FCGI_MPXS_CONNS. So the threaded.c sample will never receive multiple connections.

I tested the sample with lighttpd and nginx and the app handled only one request at once. How can I get my application to handle multiple requests? Or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: How did you test concurrency?  There is a lot of varying information available about the degree to which FCGI supports concurrency.  While I don't claim to have all the answers figured out, I have tried a multi-threaded test to verify concurrency:  Two threads configured to accept connections.  The first one will sleep for 10s after accepting a connection, blocking that thread.  A second connection is accepted and responded to.  Finally, the first thread finishes and responds.  Your question is almost a year old, but I've had troubles finding answers regarding FCGI, so hopefully this helps.

Comment: The link to threaded.c is broken. Here is a new link: https://github.com/FastCGI-Archives/fcgi2/blob/123dc84662e6b52962fb2281a4b1918d49ecdc40/examples/threaded.c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tested the threaded.c program with http_load. The program is running behind nginx. There is only one instance of the program running. If the requests are served sequentially, I would expect it would take 40 seconds for 20 requests even if sent in parallel. Here are the results (I used same numbers as Andrew Bradford - 20, 21, and 40) -

20 Requests, 20 in parallel, took 2 seconds -

```
$ http_load -parallel 20 -fetches 20 request.txt
20 fetches, 20 max parallel, 6830 bytes, in 2.0026 seconds
341.5 mean bytes/connection
9.98701 fetches/sec, 3410.56 bytes/sec
msecs/connect: 0.158 mean, 0.256 max, 0.093 min
msecs/first-response: 2001.5 mean, 2002.12 max, 2000.98 min
HTTP response codes:
  code 200 -- 20
```

21 Requests, 20 in parallel, took 4 seconds -

```
$ http_load -parallel 20 -fetches 21 request.txt
21 fetches, 20 max parallel, 7171 bytes, in 4.00267 seconds
341.476 mean bytes/connection
5.2465 fetches/sec, 1791.55 bytes/sec
msecs/connect: 0.253714 mean, 0.366 max, 0.145 min
msecs/first-response: 2001.51 mean, 2002.26 max, 2000.86 min
HTTP response codes:
  code 200 -- 21
```

40 Requests, 20 in parallel, took 4 seconds -

```
$ http_load -parallel 20 -fetches 40 request.txt
40 fetches, 20 max parallel, 13660 bytes, in 4.00508 seconds
341.5 mean bytes/connection
9.98732 fetches/sec, 3410.67 bytes/sec
msecs/connect: 0.159975 mean, 0.28 max, 0.079 min
msecs/first-response: 2001.86 mean, 2002.62 max, 2000.95 min
HTTP response codes:
  code 200 -- 40
```

So, it proves that even if the FCGI_MAX_CONNS, FCGI_MAX_REQS, and FCGI_MPXS_CONNS values are hard-coded, the requests are served in parallel.

When Nginx receives multiple requests, it puts them all in the FCGI application's queue back to back. It does not wait for a response from the first request before sending the second request. In the FCGI application, when a thread is serving the first request for whatever time, another thread is not waiting for the first one to finish, it will pick up the second request and start working on it. And so on.

So, the only time you will lose is the time it takes to read a request from the queue. This time is usually negligible compared to the time it takes to process the request.

Comment: Great answer. Now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a single answer to this question, as this does not only depends on the FastCGI protocol, it also and above all, depends on the FastCGI process manager in use. For Apache2 web servers, the FastCGI process manager may typically be `mod_fastcgi` or `mod_fcgid`. Both of these behave differently. `mod_fastcgi` seems to be multi‑thread aware, and will send concurrent requests to a FastCGI server which declared it‑self to support it. `mod_fcgid` is so far (may change in the future?) not multi‑thread aware, and will always spawn a new FastCGI server process on concurrent request and will never send concurrent requests to a FastCGI server.

All of that to say: yes, FastCGI has provision for multi‑threaded FastCGI servers, but the environment where the FastCGI server is running, also has to make this feature a reality… in practice, it may, or it may not, and unfortunately, `mod_fcgid` don't, at least so far.

If your FastCGI SDK was from `mod_fcgid`, that may be the reason why the response to the `FCGI_MAX_CONNS` management request always return the fixed hard‑coded value `1`.

You may be interested in my recent question and in two other web‑links, which all three mentions the particular topic of multi‑threaded FastCGI server:

- “[mod_fcgid: multi‑threaded FastCGI now or in a planned future?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15623422/279335)”
- “[mod_fcgi is NOT a replacement for mod_fastcgi](http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4385)”
- “[Issues with mod_fcgid and multi-threaded FastCGI application](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/201008.mbox/%3C4C7C286B.6020703@codexterous.com%3E)”

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be testing in a way that limits you to single threaded.  I had run into a similar situation, using libfcgi and lighttpd, but determined that if I used Firefox to test with, that Firefox would artificially limit submission of the HTTP request to the server until the previous one to the same server had completed.  The tool you're using to test may do something similar.

You shouldn't need to modify the `FCGI_MAX_CONNS`, `FCGI_MAX_REQS`, or `FGCI_MPXS_CONNS`.  The hard-coded values shouldn't matter to modern web servers like nginx or lighttpd.

Using a command line tool like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) and spawning 20 processes of curl at once to all hit the server results in all 20 threads activating and all 20 of the curl processes finishing at the same time, after 2 seconds, when running against the example threaded.c provided by SDK (which has an explicit `sleep(2)` call).

I have my lighttpd configuration set like:

```
fastcgi.server = (
    "/test" => (
        "test.fastcgi.handler" => (
            "socket" => "/tmp/test.fastscgi.socket",
            "check-local" => "disable",
            "bin-path" => "/tmp/a.fastcgi",
            "max-procs" => 1,
        )
    )
)
```

`max-procs` set to 1 will only spawn one copy of your fcgi program and lighttpd should report increasing "load" on the socket as requests come in before a previous request completes.

If you spawn 21 curl processes, the first 20 should finish in 2 seconds, then the last one should finish in another 2 seconds.  Spawning 40 curl processes should take almost the same duration as 21 (just over 4 seconds total).